# Who first enslaved house elves?

Tags: harry-potter, house-elves

Who first actually enslaved house elves and why did they? There is basically nothing out there to help you.

Comment: "*The practice of house-elves being attached to wizarding families goes back centuries. Currently elves are under-represented within the Department for the Regulation and Control of Magical Creatures, a fact Hermione wishes to change.*" - http://pottermore.wikia.com/wiki/House-elves

Comment: @Valorum - That quote isn't from Rowling.

Comment: @ibid - It's from a Pottermore 'moment' written by JKR

Comment: @Valorum - She didn't write any of the Pottermore moments.

Comment: @ibid - Are you sure ? Proof?

Comment: @Valorum - I figured this was commonly known (considering how Pottermore went out of their way to label specific parts as being by Rowling) but now I'm thinking of doing a self-answer about this.

Comment: @Valorum - As can be seen in [this image](http://i.imgur.com/bqb1PvU.jpg), the two moments of Book Four Chapter 14 (where your quote comes from) were both missing the red quill icon that Pottermore had used to mark moments featuring contributions from J.K. Rowling.

Comment: @ibid - Does the absence of a quill indicate that it's positively not her writing it, or merely that it doesn't contain any "*writings from JKR*"

Comment: "*The Red Quill marker will appear on the thumbnail of each Moment that contains exclusive new writing from J.K. Rowling, so you’ll never miss discovering these informative entries.*". This seems to relate to the small (500 word) essays added to the moments, not proof positive that the rest wasn't written by her, only that there's an absence of one of these essays.

Comment: @Valorum - I didn't mean that as 'proof'. I can say however, that I haven't seen any evidence of Rowling having any more direct involvement with pottermore then submitting the "writings". I also haven't seen any writing of Rowling's that appeared on Pottermore without Pottermore clearly labeling it as from her. (They even did this with the (100 word) book extracts and the (20 word) timeline entries.)

Comment: @ibid - It's worthy of its own question "***How much of the writings on Pottermore are by JKR's own hand?***"

Comment: @Valorum - Analysis of the interviews with the Pottermore team will show that they don't include Rowling in their list of sources that was available to them. Also, Rowling's interviews shows that she keeps on referring to her involvement in the role of an author submitting writings, not as an editor of the site.

Comment: @Valorum - I think I'll do a self-answer at some point. (Too busy now, though.)

Comment: @ibid - I'd be interested to read it.